# What are generators in kubernetes kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I want to generate yaml by running `kubectl`, it denotes that I should denote `--generator=something` flag within the command.

For example, to get the deployment template via `kubectl`, I should run the below command:

```
kubectl run --generator=deployment/v1beta1 nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml
```

Without mentioning `--generator` flag the CLI states in some kind that I should mention the generator flag with a proper value (e.g. `run-pod/v1`).

My question is, what is essentially a generator? What does it do? Are they some sort of object creation templates or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That was introduced in [commit 426ef93](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/426ef9335865ebef43f682da90796bd8bf976637), Jan. 2016 for Kubernetes v1.2.0-alpha.8.

[The generators](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/426ef9335865ebef43f682da90796bd8bf976637/docs/devel/kubectl-conventions.md#generators) were described as:

> Generators are `kubectl` commands that generate resources based on a set of inputs (other resources, flags, or a combination of both).
>
> The point of generators is:
>
> - to enable users using `kubectl` in a scripted fashion to pin to a particular behavior which may change in the future.
>   Explicit use of a generator will always guarantee that the expected behavior stays the same.
> - to enable potential expansion of the generated resources for scenarios other than just creation, similar to how `-f` is supported for most general-purpose commands.

And:

> Generator commands should obey to the following conventions:
>
> - A `--generator` flag should be defined. Users then can choose between different generators, if the command supports them (for example, `kubectl run` currently supports generators for pods, jobs, replication controllers, and deployments), or between different versions of a generator so that users depending on a specific behavior may pin to that version (for example, `kubectl` expose currently supports two different versions of a service generator).
> - Generation should be decoupled from creation.
>   A generator should implement the `kubectl.StructuredGenerator` interface and have no dependencies on cobra or the Factory

---

As noted by [Girish Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7570548/girish-sharma) in [the comments], and documented in [issue 93100](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93100), this was removed in 2020 ([PR 96556](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96556) and [PR 106824](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/106824).

> This PR removes the generators dependency from `kubectl create` namespace.

Comment: And it was removed in 2020. 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93100

Comment: @GirishSharma Thank you for this feedback, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Reading https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96556, I do see exactly where that feature went.